# How does this sed program work?

Tags: algorithm, sed

I found this sed program in a comment somewhere else on Stackoverflow for printing all but the last 5 lines of a file, which I've broken down and commented line-by-line:

**delete-last-5.sed**

```
# create a label "a"
:a

# - on the last line, delete the pattern space and skip any remaining commands
$d

# - increment the current line number
# - append the current line (which was previously the next line)
#   to the pattern space
N

# - on lines 2-5, branch to label "a"
2,5ba

# - print the first line of the pattern space
P

# - delete the first line of the pattern space
# - skip any remaining commands
# - if any text remains in the pattern space, when the next line is read,
#   append to (rather than overwrite) the pattern space
D
```

An example would be:

```
$ echo a b c d e f g h i j | xargs -n1 | sed -f delete-last-5.sed
a
b
c
d
e
```

However, I can't actually figure out how it works! As far as I can tell, the program execution goes something like this:

```
- _: line_number = 1
- _: pattern_space = "a"
- N: pattern_space += "\nb", line_number = 2
- 2,5ba: branch to label "a"
- N: pattern_space += "\nc", line_number = 3
- 2,5ba: branch to label "a"
- N: pattern_space += "\nd", line_number = 4
- 2,5ba: branch to label "a"
- N: pattern_space += "\ne", line_number = 5
- 2,5ba: branch to label "a"

- N: pattern_space += "\nf", line_number = 6
- P: print "a"
- D: pattern_space -= "a\n"
- _: pattern space is not empty after D, so mark pattern space to be appended to rather than overwritten

- _: line_number = 7
- _: pattern_space += "\ng"
- P: print "b"
- D: pattern_space -= "b\n"
- _: pattern space is not empty after D, so mark pattern space to be appended to rather than overwritten

- _: line_number = 8
- _: pattern_space += "\nh"
- P: print "c"
- D: pattern_space -= "c\n"
- _: pattern space is not empty after D, so mark pattern space to be appended to rather than overwritten

- _: line_number = 9
- _: pattern_space += "\ni"
- P: print "d"
- D: pattern_space -= "d\n"
- _: pattern space is not empty after D, so mark pattern space to be appended to rather than overwritten

- _: line_number = 10
- _: pattern_space += "\nj"
- $d: delete pattern_space
```

And if you gather up all those print statements, you end up with:

```
a
b
c
d
```

which is missing the 5th line.

How is the last line being printed? Where am I going wrong in my interpretation of this program?

Comment: This script gathers up and maintains a moving window of five lines in the pattern space. The use of `N`, `P` and `D` replaces the normal sed program flow of reading a line into the pattern space (PS), processing and then printing the line in the PS, with appending a new line and then the next line to what is already in the PS, printing the first line and newline and then removing it and the newline. Notice that when a line is deleted using `D` the normal flow is only resumed when the PS is empty otherwise program flow resumes at the first command of the script.

Comment: Insert `;l;` before `$d` and observe the output i.e. `sed ':a;l;$d;N;1,5ba;P;D' file`                  N.B. in the first script the `p` should be a `P`.

Comment: You're not considering actually using that script are you? sed is for simple subsitutions on individual lines (s/old/new), that is all. For anything else you should be using awk for clarity, portability, efficiency and every other desirable attribute of software. In this case you'd just save and later print an array of the previous 5 values: `awk -v n=5 'NR>n{print p[(NR-n)%n]} {p[NR%n]=$0}'`. Any time you find yourself talking about sed "pattern space" or "hold buffer" or using constructs other than s, g, and p (with -n) you are using constructs that became obsolete in the mid-1970s.

Comment: @EdMorton and why not? The Sed version actually seems to be marginally faster (0.12s vs 0.20s according to the output from `time`), the script doesn't use any GNU extensions that I'm aware of, and it's not like I slaved away over this script.

Comment: As you said in your question, even after going to the trouble of breaking it down into individual statements and commenting them all you `can't actually figure out how it works`. Now that you've had it explained to you in great detail (with the aid of GNU extensions even IF the original has none, which idk if it does or not), try enhancing it to, say, additionally print any line that contains 7 or print "here" after line 3 or print a count of output lines at the end or print the last 5 to a separate file or anything else. All trivial tweaks to the awk script and a nightmare to add to the sed.

Comment: When faced with any task that's not simple substitutions the question you should be asking is "why should I use sed?", not "why shouldn't I?" as there is almost always an alternative that's better in most relevant ways (eg clarity, performance, portability, maintainability, robustness). Want to print some values to help debug an awk script? Add `print` statements wherever you want to print whatever you want to whatever output stream (eg stderr) or file you want. Want to do the same for sed? See the accepted answer for the arcane, limited, GNU-specific conjurations +external programs available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sed debugging can be a bit of a pain. There are limited built-in options to help you: the `l` command to print the current pattern space with invisible characters such as newlines, tabs and line endings printed, and `=` (a GNU extension) to print the current line number.

Using these with your example input, printing the line number and current pattern space right before and right after the `N` command gives us this:

```
$ sed ':a;$d;=;l;N;=;l;2,5ba;P;D' <<< "$(printf 'a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng\nh\ni\nj\n')"
1
a$
2
a\nb$
2
a\nb$
3
a\nb\nc$
3
a\nb\nc$
4
a\nb\nc\nd$
4
a\nb\nc\nd$
5
a\nb\nc\nd\ne$
5
a\nb\nc\nd\ne$
6
a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf$
a
6
b\nc\nd\ne\nf$
7
b\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng$
b
...
<snip>
...
d
9
e\nf\ng\nh\ni$
10
e\nf\ng\nh\ni\nj$
e
```

Looking at the part after the `<snip>`, we've just printed `d`, and the `D` command has sent us back to the beginning of the cycle without reading a new line. We're looking at line 9, which contained `i` (already at the end of our pattern space).

Now we go through the commands:

- `$d` – ignore, we're looking at line 9, which isn't the last line (see debug output)
- `N` – append line 10; debug output shows that `j` has been appended and we're in fact looking at line 10
- `2,5ba` – ignore, we're past line 5
- `P` – print first line: **this is where the `e` comes from**
- `D` – delete first line, restart cycle, don't read next line

Next cycle:

- `$d` – *now* we're looking at the last line. Delete pattern space, print nothing, we're done!

I think the mistake in your analysis is that you increment the line number when a new cycle starts, but the only place the line number is incremented is at the `N` command. (Which you forgot to mention for the last few lines, by the way.)

If you feel like digging even deeper into your sed scripts, there is a sed debugger: [sedsed](http://aurelio.net/projects/sedsed/), written in Python. Its output for the last two lines of the command looks like this:

```
PATT:e\nf\ng\nh\ni$
HOLD:$
COMM::a
COMM:$ d
PATT:e\nf\ng\nh\ni$
HOLD:$
COMM:N
PATT:e\nf\ng\nh\ni\nj$
HOLD:$
COMM:2,5 b a
COMM:P
e
PATT:e\nf\ng\nh\ni\nj$
HOLD:$
COMM:D
PATT:f\ng\nh\ni\nj$
HOLD:$
COMM::a
COMM:$ d
```

It shows hold and pattern space for each command.

The example (for 10 instead of 5 lines) is one of the 100 sed one-liners explained on [Peteris Krumins' site](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-three/) (example 75), but the explanation is not super detailed. The same principle can be found in Eric Pement's [sed one-liners](http://www.pement.org/sed/sed1line.txt) (which were the inspiration for the "one-liners explained").

Comment: Ah, I was forgetting about `N` continuing to increment the line number after branching. That clears it up, thank you!

Comment: By the way, `=` also appears in BSD Sed, or at least in the version that ships with OS X 10.11 (dated 2005 in the manual). Sedsed, however, does _not_ run with BSD Sed because the BSD version doesn't accept `-` to mean "read from stdin", which the Sedsed script assumes. I finally got it to work by linking `gsed` to `sed` in a temporary directory.

Answer (score -1):

Your rendition of the line-number testing is out of order.  The program checks whether it's at the last line *before* adding the next.

```
:a; $d; N; 2,5ba; P; D
```

Given your `seq 10|sed -f that.sed` example, on line 9, `$d` does not trigger, line 10 is added, and line 5 is printed, leaving lines 6,7,8,9,10 in the window.  The `D` restarts the cycle and only *now* does the `$d` trigger, since you got there with the last line having been read.